# How to get Final functionality of java In c++

Tags: java, c++, object

Is there any way to make a class that can not be inherit in C++ like java.
If yes How to do that?

Comment: In C++, java already has the keyword final.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366441/final-class-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `final` keyword:

```
class imma_leaf final
{
    // Stuff...
};
```

Comment: `final` is a C++11 feature

Answer (score 3):

Try to read this article might be helpful.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4444/A-non-inheritable-class

From the article:

```
template <typename T>
class MakeFinal
{
private:
    ~MakeFinal() { };
    friend T;
};
```

Inherit from it:

```
class FinalClass : virtual public MakeFinal<FinalClass>
{ }
```

Comment: Interesting article, but links can and will die